# SQL Server constraint on row count

Tags: sql-server

I want a database level block on adding more than 3 instances of an id into a column in a mapping table.  I do not want to use a trigger or add any non-computed column to the table.  I tried an indexed view but I can't use HAVING or CAST in the query as the two non-valid examples below show.  Any ideas?

```
CREATE VIEW VW WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT col1, CAST(COUNT_BIG(*)+252 AS TINYINT) a
FROM tbl1 GROUP BY col1

CREATE VIEW VW WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT col1, COUNT_BIG(*), CAST(256 AS TINYINT) a
FROM tbl1 GROUP BY col1 HAVING COUNT(*)>3
```

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I created a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate the exact error: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c4ce/2). The error is along the lines of "Cannot create the clustered index 'IDX_V1' on view 'db_6_4c116.dbo.VW' because the select list of the view contains an expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column. Consider removing expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column from select list." The documentation mentions the prohibition against COUNT: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)/

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a function that have an id as parameters and count how many id there are in the table

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[test](@id integer)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
   SELECT @retval = COUNT(*) FROM table where id = @id
   RETURN @retval
END
```

then you can add a check constraint in the table that check if id <= 3
the test for check constraint will be

```
dbo.test(id) <= 3
```

this check is for add rows and update.